# segmentation fault for more than 9-queen problem

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, n-queens

I was reading "pointers on c" and find the very interesting 8-queen problem. I write the code for it and it worked very good and get a correct answer, 92 solutions.

Then I want to try more or less queens. I find a very weird issue. For 8 or less than 8 queens, the code is working quite perfect. For more than 8 queens, like 9,10..., there will be a segmentation fault.

Code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define SIZE 9

int conflict(int (*chess)[SIZE],int row,int col);
int next_queen(int (*chess)[SIZE],int row,int col);
int clear_previous_col(int (*chess)[SIZE],int col);
void print_chess_board(int (*chess)[SIZE]);

int total_solutions=0;
int total_print_count=0;
int chess[SIZE][SIZE];

int main(void)
{

    int row,col;

    /* initialize the chess board */
    for(row=0;row<SIZE;row++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<SIZE;col++)
        {
            chess[row][col]=0;
        }
    }

    /* start chess */
    next_queen(chess,0,0);
    printf("Totally %d solutions\n",total_solutions);

    return 0;
}

int next_queen(int (*chess)[SIZE],int row,int col)
{
    if(conflict(chess,row,col))
    {
        /* if conflicts, place queen in next row, make sure next row is not out of bound */
        if(row<SIZE-1)
        {
            next_queen(chess,row+1,col);
        }
        else
        {
             if(col<1)
             {
                 return -1;
             }
             else
             {
                 col=col-1;
                 int previous_queen_row;
                 while(col>=0 && (previous_queen_row=clear_previous_col(chess,col))==SIZE-1)
                 {
                     col=col-1;
                 }
                 if(col==-1)
                 {
                     return -1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     next_queen(chess,previous_queen_row+1,col);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        chess[row][col]=1;
        if(col<SIZE-1)
        {
            next_queen(chess,0,col+1);
        }
        else
        {
        total_solutions++;
        print_chess_board(chess);
        chess[row][col]=0;
        col=col-1;
        int previous_queen_row;
        while(col>=0 && (previous_queen_row=clear_previous_col(chess,col))==SIZE-1)
        {
            col=col-1;
        }
        if(col==-1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            next_queen(chess,previous_queen_row+1,col);
        }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void print_chess_board(int (*chess)[SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    total_print_count++;
    if(total_print_count==152)
    {
        printf("stop here!\n");
    }
    printf("print number: %d\n",total_print_count);
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",chess[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int clear_previous_col(int (*chess)[SIZE],int col)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(chess[i][col]==1)
        {
            chess[i][col]=0;
            return i;
        }
    }
    printf("return -1 col = %d\n",col);
    return -1;
}

int conflict(int (*chess)[SIZE],int row,int col)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    if(row>SIZE-1 || col>SIZE-1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if(row<0 || col<0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    /* same row conflic */
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(chess[row][i]==1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    /* same column conflict */
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(chess[i][col]==1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    /* diagonally confilic */
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            if(abs(i-row)>0 && abs(i-row)==abs(j-col) && chess[i][j]==1)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not see your program taking any input - how do you change the "count of queens" within your program? Did you try debugging your program?

Comment: With the `SIZE` macro.

Comment: You really need a `struct` to represent the board and pass that around rather than quirky array pointers.

Comment: Please state in your question how you run the program with different numbers of queens. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @Bodo it's not my question. I just noticed where the size is defined.

Comment: I think I spotted a possible out-of-bounds in `next_queen`, in `else->else->while` path, when calling `clear_prevoius_col`, but the best way to figure this out is to open the program with a debugger and checking the call trace at the time of segfault.

Comment: Nevermind, `lldb` shows clear signs of infinite recursion.

Comment: Or, rather, the problem itself gains too many levels of recursion starting from 10 pieces.

Comment: It is not easy to understand how the recursion is supposed to work. You should [edit] your question and add an explanation. This would make it easier to check for problems in your algorithm.

Comment: @Bodo thanks for your help. i am new to stackoverflow and will provide more details and explanations for any questions next time.

Comment: @MarvinZhang If you want you can [edit] you question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the program with `valgrind` on a 64-bit Ubuntu 19.10 system.

I didn't get an error with `#define SIZE 9`.

With `#define SIZE 10` it reports a stack overflow.

Next I ran it with `valgrind --num-callers=500` which is the maximum and get a stack trace like this

```
==31854== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000
==31854==    at 0x109531: conflict (queen.c:138)
==31854==    by 0x10924C: next_queen (queen.c:39)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x1092D7: next_queen (queen.c:66)
==31854==    by 0x1092D7: next_queen (queen.c:66)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x1092D7: next_queen (queen.c:66)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
==31854==    by 0x109271: next_queen (queen.c:44)
...
```

with 499 entries for `next_queen`.

You might have infinite recursion under some conditions, but I guess the nesting level gets too deep with bigger size of the board.

Apparently the limit for the board size that can be calculated with your algorithm depends on the available stack size which is different between different systems or compilers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Your answer is very clear and useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a segmentation fault bc your program asks for too much memory. Consider modifying your algorithm.

Instead of checking if the square is safe by searching the board when you try to **place a new queen**, I recommend you to mark the squares which are threatened by the queen **after you place** a new queen.

When placing a new queen, you just check your current position. If it is 0 you can place a queen, and mark it -1. And go increase every square your queen threatens by 1.

After your recursive call gets back, set the current square as 0 again and decrease the threatened squares by 1 back.

This way your program should work way faster and use way less memory. Thus, in the same computer you should be able to increase the size without segmentation fault.